# Why is $(this) called correctly for click but not on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery

why does this work by element?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
```

If you click on each one, it disappears.

But if I code it with a hover..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").hover(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
```

They all disappear together. What's the difference?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you are using the latest version? I tried this out and it worked as expected

Answer (score 6):

This is because when you are hovering above the first `<p>` element, it disappears, and therefore the second `<p>` element moves up to take its place - this process repeats until all the `<p>` elements are hidden away because your mouse will always be hovering above them.

Answer (score 4):

Try hovering over the bottom element, it will only remove the correct one.

The reason you think it's removing all of them is because it's removing the top one, then they shift to the top, and it sequentially removes them all very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that as each `p` is removed, the next `p` moves up to be under the mouse. If you hover over the bottom `<p>` first, you will see that only that one is removed.

There is no problem with the script. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zXKGk/

Answer (score 1):

Since each element moves further up, your mouse hovers over it next, thus removing it. To mitigate this, you can avoid moving new elements further up by having them retain the same space while being invisible:

```
$("p").hover(function () {
    $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JqXwv/

Answer (score 0):

If you try to hover from bottom `p` tag, you will get to know that there is nothing wrong in the take. Your `p` tags disappear because on hovering the below `p` tags just move above and take the first place, which is actually too hard to notice. You could try logging to console the event at each `p` tag.

http://jsbin.com/OpIpOpO/1/edit?html,output